# How to use group_by function on list of dataframes

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am trying to delete duplicate rows from a list of dataframes and only include the row that has the lowest absolute min (while retaining the sign).

```
gene     log2
a        0.1
b        0.3
c        -0.1
c        0.2
d        -0.2
e        -0.8
e        0.3

Desired output
a        0.1
b        0.3
c        0.1
d        -0.2
e        0.3
```

I understand that the group_by function is useful, and seems to work for a single df

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(gene) %>%
    filter(log2==min(log2))
```

However, applying this concept to a list of dfs does not seem to work

```
seq_along(dflist) %>%
    group_by(gene) %>%
    filter(log2==min(log2))

Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "list"
```

How can I remove duplicate rows and only keep the rows with the absolute min log2 (while retaining the sign)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter(log2==min(log2))` does not give you lowest absolute min, it will return the row with minimum value within each group. It can also return more than one row in a group if they share the same minimum value.

To get lowest absolute min you can arrange the data by their absolute value and take the first row by group which can be done with `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(gene, abs(log2)) %>%
  distinct(log2, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

To apply this to list of dataframes you can use `lapply` or `map` from `purrr`.

```
lapply(dflist, function(df) df %>%
  arrange(gene, abs(log2)) %>%
  distinct(log2, .keep_all = TRUE))
```

---

To use `group_by` and `filter` you can do -

```
df %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  filter(abs(log2) == min(abs(log2)))
```

and use the same code in `lapply` as shown above for list of dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would really like to use the group_by function if possible. Is there anyway to extract the min value using this function instead of rearranging the data?

Comment: It unfortunately did not work? I do not understand why though.

Comment: I have updated the answer here to use `group_by`.

Comment: Thank you! the group_by function does work and solves my problem. The abs(log2) == min(abs(log2)) will return the minimum absolute value while retaining the sign, is that correct? I do not understand why that works when the left side of the equal sign is abs(log2). Could you explain?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `min(abs(log2))` gives the minimum of absolute `log2` values. Since we are checking for absolute values only, in left hand side also we need to compare with absolute values.